# What is "juego de las formas"?

Tags: traducción

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Qué es "juego de las formas"?**

**Details in English:**

Usually I can figure something out through context, but this one has me a bit stumped.  I thought for sure I'd see an entry for this over on WordReference, but if there is, I didn't see it, so I decided to post a question about it here.  I came across the phrase in the following video:

[**Paraísos cercanos - Seychelles, naturaleza y quietud**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/paraisos-cercanos/paraisos-cercanos-seychelles-naturaleza-quietud/3302958/)

at minute 3:36.  I get the feeling, after looking at several web pages, that it refers to something specific, but nothing with any precision or consistency has really jumped out at me (at least not any that seem to make sense for this video).  Anyone happen to know?

**Detalles en español:**

Normalmente puedo averiguar algo a través del contexto, pero ésta me tiene un poco confundida.  Estaba segura que vería un artículo para ésta en [**WordReference**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?forumtitles=1&spen=juego), pero si hay, no lo vi, así que decidí publicar una pregunta en ello aquí.  Me topé con la frase en el siguiente vídeo:

[Véanse el enlace arriba.]

en el minuto 3:36. Tengo la sensación, después de mirar varias páginas web, que se refiere a algo específico, pero realmente, nada con precisión o coherencia me llamó la atención (al menos nada que parece tener sentido para este vídeo).  ¿Alguien sabe?

Comment: I have seen the expression used to mean, in a poetic sense, the shapes "playing" with themselves; combining to form a beatiful scenario. But as the expression appears just before referencing other games the interpretation of the current answers seem better. Compare with "juego de luces y sombras" https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/juego+de+luces+y+sombras.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to have a particular or idiomatic meaning. Note that *juego* can mean "game", "play" and "interplay, coordinated movement" (see the DLE: *[juego](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MaS6XPk)*, entry #12) . The verb *jugar* is similarly polysemic; in English it can mean: "to play (with something)", "to toy (with something)", "to play (a game)", "to have fun (with)", "to play around (with several items)".

So *el juego de las formas* can mean a game that is played with shapes (sculpting shapes in the sand, maybe) but it can also refer to a play (or an interplay) of shapes. This makes sense if you're talking about a landscape (with waves and dunes and mountains), as it would also make sense if you were referring to a picture with many geometric elements, for example. This meaning is more commonly found in phrases like *«el juego de luz y sombra»*, which means the interplay of light and shadow (e.g. in a building).

Comment: "Juego" as a noun can also mean "set". So "un juego de formas" could mean "a set of shapes", which adds to what you say about the interplay of shapes: you have a a set ("juego") of shapes interplaying ("jugar") between themselves to create the landscape.

Comment: Once again, the Spanish StackExchange community is treated to another fine answer by @pablodf76.  Though both answers here are worthy of reading, la marca verde goes to you.  Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is 'juego'. In this context it means 'fun activity'. It's referring to an activity consisting of drawing/sculpting shapes on the sand.

¿Jugamos al juego de las formas?
¿Jugamos al juego de los saltos?